# Help to launch java app on linux

Tags: java, linux

I have such bash script start.sh:

`export JAVA_HOME=/home/qds/bin/jdk1.6.0_22

export QDS_HOME=/home/qds


$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath $QDS_HOME/lib/*:$QDS_HOME/lib/commons/* com.qds.Main $@`

In the directory **/home/qds/lib** I have necessary libraries and my jar file, wich contains:

**com\qds\config

com\qds\entities

com\qds\hibernate

com\qds\protocols

com\qds\util

com\qds\Main.class**

but when I run ./start.sh, I have:

./start.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/qds/Main (wrong name: Main)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify what your main class is going to be in one of several ways

1. specify the main class name as an argument to the java command (just add the main class to the end of the your java command)
2. Define it in your main jar's manifest

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support wildcards in option -classpath. Try to remove * from $QDS_HOME/lib/* and from $QDS_HOME/lib/commons/*

BTW this is relevant for windows too.

Classpath should contain
1. directories
2. explicitly written jar files.

If you have many jar files you can create script that composes the command line option. 
For example on linux

```
-classpath `ls -1|tr '\n' :`
```

composes classpath delimited with colon

Comment: but shouldn't the shell expand the wildcards for him. So while true the classpath can not contain wild cards as far as the `java` command is concerened after the shell expands the wild cards it's just a list of files

Comment: but then I just saw he has multiple entries seperated by `:` which means the shell want be expanding anything, carryon :)